# Can't add metadata Tag to .mkv video in file explorer because I need permission from myself to modify the file

Tags: windows-10, permissions, metadata, matroska

I'm on Win 10 1709. I can modify, delete, and rename files but can't add tags. Windows says I need permission from myself to modify the file when tagging.  Below is a .gif of the issue.  I already have ownership of the file and directory.

Edit: windows says I need permission for editing any kind of Metadata, not just tagging.
If I change the file extension to jpg, it asks for permission then appears to succeed. However,upon re-selecting the file, the metadata changes disappear. If I add tags to an actual jpg, no permissions are asked for and the metadata changes persist.
The issue seems to be .mkv specific. For other video types such as .mp4, Windows doesn't even give options to tag or modify metadata. However, for .avi files it does give you an option to rate the file x/5 stars.  If I rate it, the same `Access Denied Need permission from self` issue presents itself.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are *really* Derek?

Comment: I almost wonder if its drive letter strangeness. What happens when you change that? Is this an internal or external drive?

Comment: Are you sure you can modify the actual file content? (Maybe try tweaking one of its bytes with a hex editor like [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm).) Also, could you show the result of `icacls` on the file in a command prompt?

Comment: I can successfully modify bytes with XVI32 and Notepad++. icacls basically says the same thing as Windows Security Settings. Here is the icacls results: https://gist.github.com/DerekZiemba/9002c53d1504a1d038c317b31b730815

Comment: If I change the file extension to jpg, it asks for permission then succeeds. However, if I de-select the file and re-select it, the metadata changes disappear. If I add tags to an actual jpg, no permissions are asked for and the metadata changes persist.

Comment: @Ben N I can confirm it is not drive letter specific.